# ¿como hago una validacion de campos vacios en android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo una clase `registroUsuarios` como hago para que me entregue un mensaje de campos vacios en mi app?. quería saber si de esa forma la validación la probe en mi aplicativo no me registro, pero no me mostró el toast, creo q hay que hacer algo en el `onClick` pero no se como realizarlo.
se agradece la ayuda.

```
     public void onClick(View view){
        
        registrarUsuarios();
      //  registrarUsuariosSql();
    }
    
    private void registrarUsuarios() {
        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this, "bd_usuarios", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
    if (campoId.toString().isEmpty()||campoNomCompleto.toString().isEmpty()||campoCorreo.toString().isEmpty()||campoContrasenia.toString().isEmpty()
            ||campoContraseniaRep.toString().isEmpty()) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LLene todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_ID, campoId.getText().toString());
                values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE_COMPLETO, campoNomCompleto.getText().toString());
                values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CORREO, campoCorreo.getText().toString());
                values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CONTRASENIA, campoContrasenia.getText().toString());
                values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CONTRASENIA_REP, campoContraseniaRep.getText().toString());

                Long idResultado = db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO, Utilidades.CAMPO_ID, values);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Id Registro: " + idResultado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                db.close();
                limpiar();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de sintaxis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No mostró el toast, pero marco algún mensaje de error en el LogCat?

Comment: no, ningun error le toma , me sigue igual registrando usuarios cuando coloca los campos vacios, la del amigo abajo cuando paso el codigo

Comment: Es que no esta realizando la validación correctamente del contenido de los EditText, debes usar getText().toString().isEmpty() , revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: vale muchas gracias .creo al comun me faltaba jsjsj gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas obteniendo el valor `String` de los `EditText` lo cual es incorrecto:

```
  if (campoId.toString().isEmpty()||campoNomCompleto.toString().isEmpty()||campoCorreo.toString().isEmpty()||campoContrasenia.toString().isEmpty()
            ||campoContraseniaRep.toString().isEmpty()) {
```

**Debes obtener el texto en el `EditText` usando `getText()` y de esta forma puedes validar correctamente usando `isEmpty()`**:

```
  if (campoId.getText().toString().isEmpty()||campoNomCompleto.getText().toString().isEmpty()||campoCorreo.getText().toString().isEmpty()||campoContrasenia.getText().toString().isEmpty()
            ||campoContraseniaRep.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: gracias !!!! me salvaste jsjsj

Comment: Excelente Cristian, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Estas condicionando pero dentro de la misma condición ejecutas tu sentencia SQL lo que debes hacer es ejecutar la sentencia dentro de un else así validas cuando el edittext este vacío y cuando no lo este que la ejecute:

```
private void registrarUsuarios() {

ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this, "bd_usuarios", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

    if (campoId.toString().isEmpty()||campoNomCompleto.toString().isEmpty()||campoCorreo.toString().isEmpty()||campoContrasenia.toString().isEmpty()
            ||campoContraseniaRep.toString().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LLene todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        try {
           
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_ID, campoId.getText().toString());
            values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE_COMPLETO, campoNomCompleto.getText().toString());
            values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CORREO, campoCorreo.getText().toString());
            values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CONTRASENIA, campoContrasenia.getText().toString());
            values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CONTRASENIA_REP, campoContraseniaRep.getText().toString());

            Long idResultado = db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO, Utilidades.CAMPO_ID, values);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Id Registro: " + idResultado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.close();
            limpiar();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de sintaxis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: m.. no me resulto pa

Comment: Disculpa no había comprendido muy bien la pregunta aunque de todas maneras no veo porque metes la sentencia dentro de la condición sin un "else" eso deberías revisarlo para evitar errores, pero que bueno que ya te ayudaron, saludos!